# Skeletal animations in C# SFML 2D

Tags: skeletal-animation

I'm completely green when it comes to skeletal animations in 2D. I create a platform game and I got graphics for it - body parts from which to stick the character. My problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to go about it. The question is: How do you implement animations in the game?
I could do it frame by frame from previously glued body parts, but I need the character to look at the mouse cursor, so it falls off. I am asking for some ideas.

Comment: Have a look at http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-in-depth#Development. Also ask at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

About your problem, if you want all parts of your character look at the mouse, you should rotate your character, if just a part (like character's head) you need to rotate the head.

I could give you some methods to implement animation that I known

- Draw animation frame by frame: simple, easy to approach and handle but hard to scale up.
- Separate character into many parts and each part has a unique animation: flexible, good for scale up but hard to handle due to you must ensure all parts are stick together in a right way (from scratch without tools or engine). I think this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXIuizGzY2A) may help you to know more the way their create skeletal animation in Unity (same as [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/)).

  Hope it help.